# how jdk1.0 lacked clean separation between native and Java code?

Tags: java-native-interface, native, java

From [IBM Link :](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jni/index.html)

> The JDK 1.0 release included an earlier native-method interface that lacked clean 
>       separation between native and Java code. In this interface, natives would reach 
>       directly  into JVM structures and so could not be portable across JVM implementations, 
>       platforms, or even versions of the JDK. Upgrading an application with a substantial 
>       number of natives using the JDK 1.0 model was expensive, as was developing natives 
>       that could run with multiple JVM implementations.

What is meant by *natives would reach 
    directly  into JVM structures and so could not be portable across JVM implementations* ? I don't understand this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [documentation for the current JNI](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/intro.html) contains this interesting bit about the old interface:

> JDK 1.0 was shipped with a native method interface. Unfortunately, there were two major reasons that this interface was unsuitable for adoption by other Java VMs.
>
> First, the native code accessed fields in Java objects as members of C structures. However, the Java Language Specification does not define how objects are laid out in memory. If a Java VM lays out objects differently in memory, then the programmer would have to recompile the native method libraries.
>
> ...

This means that the native code could *directly* access the values of objects in memory, instead of going through some API. That's the equivalent of direct access to a field in Java, as opposed to using getters/setters. This means that the underlying layout of the fields could never be changed without breaking compatibility with any code that uses that old native interface.

I've found a [copy of the native method tutorial from the JDK 1.0.2 here](http://journals.ecs.soton.ac.uk/java/tutorial/native/index.html). It includes a section on [handling Java objects from native code](http://journals.ecs.soton.ac.uk/java/tutorial/native/implementing/objects.html).

The modern JNI gives access to Java object fields only via method calls. This way the layout of objects and many other things can change without breaking compatibility.